# Need Rally Burndown chart API implementation to show in our dashboard

Tags: rally, burndowncharts

I am creating Dashboard(dashing.IO) in which i want to display the Rally Burn down chart.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your app in an html file and then embed it in an iframe element in a widget.
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

The burn down chart is accessible via the Standard Report component:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport

Comment: I tried to make the api requests by sending this in headers, cookies. But getting the "getaddrinfo name or service not known error" 

There is no proper documentation about how to send the API key in apis requests, like which key and pair we should send either in headers or in cookies.

Comment: As long as you're appending the apiKey parameter in the iframe src url you should be good to go.  I forgot though, that there is currently a defect around certain reports not working with api keys, so you may be running up against that.  Hopefully that will be fixed shortly...

Comment: The defect around using the StandardReport component externally with an api key has been resolved so you should be good to go!

Comment: We have used different approach to render burn down with IterationCumulativeFlowData webservices API https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/